# Android Screen Refresh

Tags: android

I have written my own screen dim controller. If the device is idle for 15 seconds the screen will dim, once the user presses the screen the screen will become brighter. Touching the screen the timer is reset.

Now I have two activities. One is for the main application screen one is for a settings menu. Both are a subclass of an activity I called PCIActivity.

If the PCIActivity is where I control the screen dim. The main application page is made of three fragments, each of which is responsible for their own background color. When the PCIActivity decides it is time to dim the display I want to change the background color of the three fragments.

Is there a clean efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hi! You could use public methods in fragments, then when it's time to change background in these fragments, just fire new created changeToColor(Color color); method, where you could put your change color logic.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `Observer pattern`. Your `DimController` should contain a `observable` that fires every time the screen needs to dim. Your `Fragments`/`Activities` should `subscribe` to the `observable`. When the screen dims everyone subscribed gets the message that they are supposed to dim.
I recommend a library called `RxJava`(there is a `Kotlin` ver. too).
I would avoid making `public` functions in your `Fragments`/`Activity` it leads to tight coupling. With the example below ANYONE can `subscribe` to the dim messages and the `DimController` is none the wiser.

```
Example:

       // DimController
        
        public static String DIM_MESSAGE = "DIM_MESSAGE";
        private PublishSubject<String> messageSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        
        public subscribeToMessages(Subscriber<String> subscriber){
              messageSubject
                     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) //optional
                     .observeOn(Schedulers.io()) //optional remember UI needs to update on UI thread
                     .subscribe(subscriber);
        }
        //When you need to dim.
        private void doDim(){
            messageSubject.onNext(DIM_MESSAGE);
        }
        
       // Fragment/Activity
        private DisposableSubscriber dimSubscriber;
        
        private DisposableSubscriber getDimSubscriber(){
              return new DisposableSubscriber<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onNext(String message) {
                            if(!isAdded()) //avoid changing view stuff if not attached.
                                 return;
                            //any message
                             switch(message){
                                 case DimController.DIM_MESSAGE:
                                  //change colors
                                 break;
                                 default:
                             }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onError(Throwable t) {}
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {}
              };
        }
        
        @Override
        public onResume(){
            super.onResume();
            dimSubscriber = getDimSubscriber();
            dimController.subscribeToMessages(dimSubscriber); //whatever is the best way for you to retrieve the dimController
        }
        @Override
        public onPause(){
            super.onPause();
            dimSubscriber.dispose();
        }
```

Comment: This is very interesting and I will keep this in mind for a future improvement